# Is there any phase delay between displacement and driving force in undamped driven oscillation when the driving frequency is below resonant frequency?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I know that there is phase delay in damped driven oscillation but I want to know is there any phase delay in undamped driven oscillation when we apply sinusoidal driving force. When driving force is maximum, displacement is also maximum as well right?

Comment: It depends on initial conditions. In general case there is phase shift but for very specific initial conditions they oscillate with the same phase.

Comment: The initial conditions should be equilibrium right? Where the position is at equilibrium and velocity is zero.

Comment: I have seen a lot of differential equation solutions (particular solution) for undamped driven oscillation. Almost all of them states that the phase delay is always zero.

Comment: The initial conditions could be arbitrary. But even for zero initial conditions phase shift  is not zero for force frequency below resonance.

Comment: Even there is no damping force, there is phase delay also?

Comment: Solution is the linear combination of $e^{i \omega t}, e^{i \omega_0 t}$, where $\omega, \omega_0$ are frequencies of force and free oscillator.

Comment: If we just looks for particular solution, is there any phase delay?

Comment: Yes, there are exist special initial conditions to eliminate harmonic $e^{i\omega_0}$. Is your question about this case?

Comment: So weird. I watch this lecture. If damping constant is zero, there must be no phase delay. (Lecture from Walter Lewin)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_DmzZcQR7A&t=1123s